# Is PHP Object Generator a good choice for a big project?

Tags: php, object, generator

I'm planning the development of a platform "similar" to a social network. Is a project that includes some functionalities like chat, messaging, profiles, advertising but also has some financial and file management modules.

As for the beginning of the project I will definitely use [POG](http://www.phpobjectgenerator.com) considering the deadline and also because it will have a low demand (50000 users) on the first months. 
But (here is my concern) as the db grows I am not sure if it would be a good choice to keep like this for the long term or if is better to think about to start a new version of the project ready to be deploy in a near future.

Comment: I'd go for [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/)

Comment: @DCoder Correction; Decent Frameworks like Zend Framework 2 or Symfony2. Yii and Laravel are TERRIBLE. Grisales, I would recommend Doctrine2 as well.

Comment: Decent frameworks usually include their own code generators that can create model classes without you having to manually retype the DB columns. Classes created that way are sure to be better than those generated by a random online tool.